# Rails disable eager loading for specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading, activeresource

I'm writing a Rails application with functionality that interfaces with a third-party API (streamsend) via ActiveResource. I'm using shopify's fork of ActiveResource for thread-safe operation because different users of my application will have their own streamsend API client ID's and secret keys and I don't want my app to step on them when interfacing with the third-party API.

I have this in my controller associated with an `around_action` filter:

```
private

# set StreamSend credentials in every request
def set_ss_credentials
  StreamSend.site,
    StreamSend.user,
      StreamSend.password = current_user_credentials
  yield
ensure
  StreamSend.site =
    StreamSend.user =
      StreamSend.password = nil
end

DEFAULT_SITE, DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASSWORD = [
Rails.application.secrets.streamsend_api_endpoint, "username", "password" ]

def current_user_credentials
  current_user.present? ?
    [ Rails.application.secrets.streamsend_api_endpoint, current_user.ss_userid, current_user.ss_key ] :
    [ DEFAULT_SITE, DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASSWORD ]
end
```

And in my model:

```
class StreamSend < ActiveResource::Base
  self.format = :xml
  def self.audience
    @audience ||= StreamSend::Audience.find(:first)
  end
end
```

The site and credentials are meant to be fed in via the controller action and the current user that's logged in.

This works fine when using WEBrick, but because the default setting for Rails in production mode is `config.eager_load = true`, my application won't start because the actual model is lacking a site and credentials as well.

Is there a way I can tell `eager_load` to ignore my ARes-dependent models but eager load all my actual database models?

Answer (score 0):

The errors when launching in production mode came from this:

```
def self.audience
  @audience ||= StreamSend::Audience.find(:first)
end
```

Hard coding `audience` to 1 by default allowed me to launch the application in production mode. This is fine for now because Streamsend only supports one audience per account.